# web.DataReader + "fred": Failed Downloads

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

Running this in jupyter notebook:

```
start = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=5 * 365)
end = datetime.date.today()
df = web.DataReader(["sp500", "NASDAQCOM", "CBBTCUSD"], "fred", start, end)
```

Gives me this error:

```
[*********************100%%**********************]  3 of 3 completed

3 Failed downloads:
['CBBTCUSD', 'NASDAQCOM', 'SP500']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
```

How can I resolve it?

[image: error message]

I tried modifying the time zone, and looking up the tickers on the FRED website, but that didn't help much either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.